# How to fix this spurious face (?)

Tags: mesh

It was a cube with an additional loop made by Ctrl+R. I wanted to move inwards one of the faces, but without pulling the edge of its neighbour. Thus I Ctrl+Shift+R the neighbour. Then I just moved one of the faces to the left, the dark one in front:

[image]

making a dent in the cube.

Some time later. I noticed a flickering dark triangle below. How to get rid of this?  I tried various cleanups of the mesh, they did nothing.

Undo is out of question, as I did many other changes in the meantime. Unless there is a local object undo, but I am not sure if there is one in Blender. I do not want to delete this object, as it is carefully measured. I tried to cut the problematic bottom with a cube, but most CSG operations work badly with this mesh - intersection produces a plane even if there is a substantial overlap, difference does nothing.

Here is the source of the mesh: [image]

And here is the wireframe, as asked by batFINGER: [image]

**UPDATE**: the face overlapping with the triangle had one of its edges along the full width of the mesh. I finally deleted the whole bottom (somehow) and created a new one with F.

Comment: Just select the bad face and delete it? If you're having difficulty making the selection. and are selecting good faces along the way, just H hide them and try again?

Comment: @RobinBetts This triangle forms a combo with the bottom face. I can only delete them together, and I do not know how to create a new face between selected points.

Comment: Delete the two long edges of triangle?

Comment: These edges cannot be selected. I guess that they do not exist, as the triangle is not a "proper" face.

Comment: F to make a face between two edges, ... hard to tell from your illustration, there may be some other problems with the topo, making some repairs necessary, share your file  at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, if you like.

Comment: I added the source.

Comment: A wireframe may help shed some light too.  Select non manifold?

Comment: I can delete the face and use F, but when I try, even if it looks good, the connections are bad - not really a manifold.

Comment: @batFINGER I added the wireframe. I do not understand what you mean by "select non manifold".

Comment: Removing 4 doubles and Selecting the two vertical edges of the "removed weird face" and fill worked for me. Strange.. hopefully RB is working up an answer right now.

Comment: I selected one of the vertices, which turned out to overlap with another, deleted it, it made the entire bottom disappear. Then I used F and it seems that I have a proper manifold now. By the way, if there are overlapping vertices, any way of toggling the selection between them?

Comment: Hide a face would be one way I suppose. If you don't want doubles would remove them. The remove (mesh > merge > distance) doubles reported that 4 were removed.  Would also look into making quads from ngon faces (> 4 verts)